# Clicking links/opening a link in a new tab recently busted in IE10

Tags: bug, stack-exchange

So, I'm using IE10 in Windows 8 right now as my primary browser, and with a recent update (past couple days, as of 5/24/2013), the site has been exhibiting buggy behavior.

I first saw this when I open the browser up and then navigate to SuperUser's Root Access chatroom. If I click the SuperUser logo on the bottom right corner of the window, it will cause IE to hang for about 30-60 seconds, spike the CPU usage to 100%, and then open the superuser.com page in a *new window* as opposed to a new tab. If I close that window, from then on, the site apparently behaves normally. That is, unless I try and open a new tab. It will show the new tab page but a new tab will not spawn in the tab bar. Closing will close the current tab and (I suppose) close the website I was previously viewing, even though the page itself disappeared.

I also am recently having issues with clicking certain links. I clicked the StackExchange drop menu link on the top left and nothing opens. I had to right click it and select "open" in order for it to open. Logging in, I also had to type in my OpenID manually since clicking the Google link didn't do anything.

Did something change in the website code recently? It seems to have triggered some (likely) corner cases in IE, or at least is messing up with how IE handles tabbing and mouse input.

I will note that I tested this mostly in SuperUser (since I visit that site most often). However, I did see it on other sites, briefly, as well (including this one). I do not see this behavior at all on any other website that I navigate to that's not in the SE network. I also don't see this in other browsers at all.

I've checked my settings, cleared cookies and cache completely, and disabled Tracking Protection, but it didn't help. I tried seeing if anything showed up in the developer console (when I press F12) but nothing appeared (though that doesn't mean nothing went wrong, either).

Does anyone have any insight? Does anyone else see this happening to them? Also, is this the right place to ask this question?

Comment: Yes, this is the right place. No, no idea - we changed nothing in regards to the logo and the link, and it isn't anything special - it doesn't even have a `target` attribute.

Comment: @Oded It isn't even to do with the logo or that specific link. If I open IE10 up to any SE page, right-clicking and selecting "open in new tab" will reproduce the behavior, as well, on any link that I've tried.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Maybe your graphics drivers? When were they updated?

Comment: I ran a bios update but I think that's it. It's on my tablet (with Intel HD 4000 graphics or some such). I'm open to the suggestion that it's just me, but I've checked a lot and can't figure out why it'd only affect SE, and not other sites.

Comment: I have the same problem!!  I am using Win7 with IE10.  It used to work fine, but a couple days ago something changed (new patch?) and now the "Right Click -> Open in new Tab" doesn't work.  It opens in a new Window instead.  Also middle button click on a link formerly would open a new tab, but now it opens a new window.   Please help! this is very annoying.

Comment: @JohnHenckel I got it fixed. I'll post a solution. Also, since it apparently has nothing to do with this site, we should probably have this moved to SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue. It was apparently a corruption in IE's settings.

What I did was just do a full reset of Internet Explorer's settings. Open up Internet Options and click on the Advanced tab. Then click the button that says *Reset...* under "Reset Internet Explorer settings". This will reset everything. Internet Explorer should work properly after you restart it.